# How can I invert the poles of an OP-AMP in circuitikz?

Tags: circuitikz, opamp

I have an op-amp in my circuit, but I would like the + pole to be above and the - pole to be downward. I don't know how to do that. (Sorry I can't upload an image, it is my first post)

Can anybody help me please?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
(0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
;\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `yscale=-1`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz} 
  \draw (0,0) node[op amp] (opamp1) {}
  (opamp1.+) node[left ] {$v_+$}
  (opamp1.-) node[left ] {$v_-$};
  \draw (3,0) node[op amp,yscale=-1] (opamp2) {}
  (opamp2.+) node[left ] {$v_+$}
  (opamp2.-) node[left ] {$v_-$};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is kind of problematic solution, because `up` and `down` nodes are swept, and possible node name is inverted too.

Comment: @Pygmalion --- trying to get a necromancer badge for Halloween, I have posted another answer... ;-)

Comment: @Rmano Sorry for a late response, I've only logged into SE today.

Answer (score 6):

To clear up any confusion (I know I sure had to Google around for a couple of hours after discovering this thread): as alluded to by Rmano in the *comments* on his answer, CircuiTikZ now supports inverting/flipping opamp inputs natively using the option `noinv input up` (which means "draw the non-inverting (i.e. +) input as the upper terminal"), turned off by the default `noinv input down`. In fact, the result you get using the code in Rmano's answer is now less optimal than what CircuiTikZ offers!

A comparison of the answers (see figure below):

1. [Accepted answer by Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49436/203081):

   ```
   \begin{circuitikz}
       \draw node[op amp, yscale=-1] (myopamp1) {$A$};
   \end{circuitikz}
   ```
2. [Rmano's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/457577/203081) (**with his `makeatletter ... makeatother` in the preamble**):

   ```
   \begin{circuitikz}
       \draw node[op amp, noinv up] (myopamp1) {$A$};
   \end{circuitikz}
   ```
3. Native options implemented in CircuiTikZ since:

   ```
   \begin{circuitikz}
       \draw node[op amp, noinv input up] (myopamp1) {$A$};
   \end{circuitikz}
   ```

[image: Inverting/flipping opamp terminals in CircuiTikZ: answer comparison]

You can find more information about general amplifiers under section 3.22.2 of the CircuiTikZ 1.3.0 manual (available on CTAN as of writing).

Comment: oh, yes... because since then I have been "promoted" as one of the keepers of `circuitikz`; so I have added a better version of the code to the package, and adding the code here will really downgrade the op-amp shape to an older one!

Comment: ...and this is quite nice to see. This was my first shot at a change in `circuitikz`... and look what has happened. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want just to switch `+` and `-`, you have to modify the definition of the `op amp`. What I have done is to add an option `noinv up` (and the corresponding `noinv down`, in the case you want to reset a style) that switches the inverting and no inverting input letting the other anchors where they are.

Additionaly, I added anchors `in up` and `in down` for the input that is "up" and "down" independently from the new option.

The code is the one between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. The code need the latest version of `circuitikz` ([you can find it at github](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz)) due to unfathomable reasons; probably if you want to stick with your version you need to copy your definition of the `op amp` and replicate the changes I did (marked in the code between `%%% RG:` marks). It seems long and complex, but basically is a minimal change of the original code...

PS: I have prepared a [pull request for the tikzcircuit github cod](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pulls)e with this and more things...

Result:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, oldvoltagedirection]{circuitikzgit}
% needs the latest version of circuitikz, see github (dunno why) 
% \usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
%
\makeatletter
%%% RG: added the option and the code to switch
\newif\ifpgf@circuit@oa@plusup\pgf@circuit@oa@plusupfalse
\pgfkeys{/tikz/noinv up/.add code={}{\pgf@circuit@oa@plusuptrue}}
\ctikzset{noinv up/.add code={}{\pgf@circuit@oa@plusuptrue}}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/noinv down/.add code={}{\pgf@circuit@oa@plusupfalse}}
\ctikzset{noinv down/.add code={}{\pgf@circuit@oa@plusupfalse}}
%%% RG stop 
\pgfdeclareshape{op amp}
{
    \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
    \savedanchor\northwest{%
        \pgf@y=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/op amp/height}\pgf@circ@Rlen
        \pgf@y=.5\pgf@y
        \pgf@x=-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/op amp/width}\pgf@circ@Rlen
        \pgf@x=.5\pgf@x
    }
    \anchor{south}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@y=-\pgf@y
        \pgf@x=0pt
    }
    \anchor{north}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@x=0pt
    }
    \savedanchor\left{%
        \pgf@y=0pt
    }
    \anchor{leftedge}
    {\left
        \pgf@x = \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/op amp/port width}\pgf@x
    }
    %%% RG: added the fixed anchors
    \savedanchor\inOneFixed{%
        \pgf@y=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/op amp/height}\pgf@circ@Rlen
        \pgf@y=.5\pgf@y
        \pgf@y=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/op amp/input height}\pgf@y
        \pgf@x=-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/op amp/width}\pgf@circ@Rlen
        \pgf@x=.5\pgf@x
    }
    \anchor{in up}{
        \inOneFixed
    }
    \anchor{in down}{
        \inOneFixed
        \pgf@y=-\pgf@y
    }
    %%% RG stop 
    \savedanchor\inOne{%
        \pgf@y=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/op amp/height}\pgf@circ@Rlen
        \pgf@y=.5\pgf@y
        \pgf@y=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/op amp/input height}\pgf@y
        \pgf@x=-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/op amp/width}\pgf@circ@Rlen
        \pgf@x=.5\pgf@x
        %%% RG: added the conditional flip
        \ifpgf@circuit@oa@plusup\pgf@y=-\pgf@y\fi
        %%% RG stop 
    }
    \anchor{-}{
        \inOne
    }
    \anchor{+}{
        \inOne
        \pgf@y=-\pgf@y
    }
    \savedanchor\up{%
        \pgf@y=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/op amp/height}\pgf@circ@Rlen
        \pgf@y=.5\pgf@y
        \pgf@x=-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/op amp/width}\pgf@circ@Rlen
        \pgf@x=.5\pgf@x
        \pgf@circ@res@up = \pgf@y
        \pgf@circ@res@right = -\pgf@x
        \pgf@circ@res@left = \pgf@x
        \pgfpointlineattime{
            \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/op amp/up pos}}{
            \pgfpoint{
            \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/op amp/port width}\pgf@circ@res@left}
        {\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        {\pgfpoint{.7\pgf@circ@res@right}{0pt}}
    }
    \anchor{up}{
        \up
    }
    \anchor{down}{
        \up
        \pgf@y=-\pgf@y
    }
    \anchor{out}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@y=0pt
        \pgf@x=-\pgf@x
    }
    \anchor{west}{
        \left
    }
    \anchor{east}{
        \left
        \pgf@x=-\pgf@x
    }

    \backgroundpath{
        \pgfsetcolor{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/color}}


        \northwest
        \pgf@circ@res@up = \pgf@y
        \pgf@circ@res@down = -\pgf@y
        \pgf@circ@res@right = -\pgf@x
        \pgf@circ@res@left = \pgf@x

        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
            {\pgf@circ@res@left}
        {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/op amp/input height}\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
            {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/op amp/port width}\pgf@circ@res@left}
        {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/op amp/input height}\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        %%% RG: added the conditional for printing labels + and -
    \pgftext[left, at=\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/op amp/port width}\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/op amp/input height}\pgf@circ@res@up}]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/op amp/font} \ifpgf@circuit@oa@plusup$+$\else$-$\fi}
    %%% RG stop

        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
            {\pgf@circ@res@left}
        {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/op amp/input height}\pgf@circ@res@down}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
            {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/op amp/port width}\pgf@circ@res@left}
        {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/op amp/input height}\pgf@circ@res@down}}
        %%% RG: added the conditional for printing labels + and -
    \pgftext[left, at=\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/op amp/port width}\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/op amp/input height}\pgf@circ@res@down}]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/op amp/font} \ifpgf@circuit@oa@plusup$-$\else$+$\fi}
    %%% RG stop

        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.7\pgf@circ@res@right}{0pt}}
        \pgfsetrectcap
        \pgfusepath{draw}


        \pgfscope
        \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/thickness}\pgflinewidth}
        \pgftransformxshift{.7\pgf@circ@res@left}
        \pgf@circ@res@step=\pgf@circ@res@right
        \advance\pgf@circ@res@step by -\pgf@circ@res@left
        \pgf@circ@res@step=.7\pgf@circ@res@step

        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@step}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
        \pgfpathclose
        \pgfusepath{draw}
        \endpgfscope



    }
}
\makeatother
\def\coord(#1){coordinate(#1)}
\def\coord(#1){node[circle, red, draw, inner sep=1pt,pin={[red, overlay, inner sep=0.5pt, font=\tiny, pin distance=0.1cm, pin edge={red, overlay,}]75:#1}](#1){}}
\def\coordd(#1){node[circle, red, draw, inner sep=1pt,pin={[red, overlay, inner sep=0.5pt, font=\tiny, pin distance=0.1cm, pin edge={red, overlay,}]-145:#1}](#1){}}
\ctikzset{tripoles/mos style/arrows, bipoles/thickness=1, }
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[ american, ]
    %
    \draw[cyan, dotted] (-2,-2) grid (2,5);
    \node at (0,0) [op amp](OA1){};
    \node at (OA1.up) [vcc]{};
    \node at (OA1.down) [vee]{};
    \foreach \a in {+,-,up,down,out} \path (OA1.\a) \coord(\a);
    \foreach \a in {in up, in down} \path (OA1.\a) \coordd(\a);
    \node at (0,3) [op amp, noinv up](OA2){};
    \node at (OA2.up) [vcc]{};
    \node at (OA2.down) [vee]{};
    \foreach \a in {+,-,up,down,out} \path (OA2.\a) \coord(\a);
    \foreach \a in {in up, in down} \path (OA2.\a) \coordd(\a);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I understand right, if your pull request is accepted, the `circuitikz` library will include `noinv up`, `up` and `down` additions?  What is current status of your pull request?

Comment: @Pygmalion More or less --- I have changed the keys to `noinv input up` / `noinv input down` / `noinv output up` /  `noinv output down` (for the full differential amplifier). I do not have any info on the pull request, but you can check out my version at https://github.com/Rmano/circuitikz  (the changes are in che CHANGELOG.md file --- and in the manual).

Comment: OK.  But since I am using MikTeX on Windows, I would rather wait to see official version accepting your changes.  If you ever get information that they are accepted, I (and other readers) will be very grateful if you drop that information here.

Comment: @Pygmalion, ok. Anyway, using the git version (both mine or the upstream one) could be as easy as dropping the circuitikzgit.sty file in the same directory as you file... :-;