# TikZ, customize symbol of operational amplifier

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, tikz-node, circuits, customize

In TikZ (used including the package `circuitikz`), the code

```
\draw (0,0) node[op amp] (OA1) {};
```

creates an operational amplifier with its standard shape. I would like to customize it, for example adding an internal resistance with its own label:

[image]

I would like to define, for example, a `custom op amp` and use it as

```
\draw (0,0) node[op amp] (OA2) {};
```

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/457577/74786) is the most relevant example I found, but the code inside

```
\pgfdeclareshape{op amp}
```

is quite unreadable for me. It looks very different form a normal TikZ draw, where you can try and check each step by compiling the document.

Are there any examples on how to use `pgfdeclareshape`? Or can I draw my shape as a normal TikZ picture and then re-import it as a `custom op amp`?

Suggestions about these ones, or any other equivalent solution, are welcome.

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[american]

\draw (0,0) node[op amp] (OA1) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want to stick with “normal” Ti*k*Z syntax, try a `\pic`. It can contain nodes that you can access from the outside and use for positioning.

Comment: Are you sure you are using tikz-circuit-lib and not circuitikz? They are quite different things... And given that you did not provide a small, compilabile self-contained example, we can't really say.

Comment: @Rmano I'm sorry for not specifying it: I'm *including* the package `circuitikz`, otherwise the code does not work. However, the drawing is inside a `tikzpicture` block. I updated the question including an MWE.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I can try! Do you know some examples?

Comment: Notice that `circuitikz` symbols *can* have problems when used in `pic`s. Mainly, rotation can create problems. Another approach is to define a subcircuit, see section 3.4 in the manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can produce this figure:
[image: op amp with resistor]
with the [circuitikz](https://ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz) package (from doc p. 145, version 1.6.7) :

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[]
  \draw (0,0) node[plain amp](Amp){};
  \draw (Amp.bin up) -- ++(0.2,0)
  coordinate (tmp)
  node[right] {$+$}
  to[R, resistors/scale=0.5]
  (tmp|-Amp.bin down)
  node[right] {$-$}
  -- (Amp.bin down);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

But I'm not sure if it's what's your looking for.

Comment: +1, I think this is the easiest way. You can encapsulate the added "decorations" easily in a macro.

Comment: Yes, it works and it is simple. It's ok! Thank you!